# SQL update query syntax with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sql-update

Can anyone find my error in this query?  I'm using SQL Server 2000 and I want to update all entries in the CostEntry table to the corresponding value in the ActiveCostDetails table.  The where clause DOES work with a select statement.

```
    UPDATE CostEntry CE 
INNER JOIN ActiveCostDetails As AD ON CostEntry.lUniqueID = ActiveCostDetails.UniqueID
       SET CostEntry.sJobNumber = ActiveCostDetails.JobNumber
     WHERE CostEntry.SEmployeeCode = '002'
       AND SubString(CostCentre, 1, 1) = sDepartmentCode
       AND substring(CostCentre, 3, 1) = sCategoryCode
       AND substring(CostCentre, 5, 2) = sOperationCode
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies- Thanks for looking, but this query has the same effect as the original (not working due to syntax error).  I believe this is because SQL server ignores spaces and carriage returns in a query.

Comment: I just reformatted what you posted--easier to read, easier to help

Comment: Ok ponies, I understand.  I was working off an example, online...   http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1958  But your way is better.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `SET` needs to come before the `FROM\JOIN\WHERE` portion of the query.

```
UPDATE CE
SET sJobNumber = AD.JobNumber
FROM CostEntry CE 
    INNER JOIN ActiveCostDetails As AD 
        ON CE.lUniqueID = AD.UniqueID
WHERE CE.SEmployeeCode = '002'
    AND SubString(CostCentre, 1, 1) = sDepartmentCode
    AND substring(CostCentre, 3, 1) = sCategoryCode
    AND substring(CostCentre, 5, 2) = sOperationCode
```

Comment: +1: [SS2000 Update documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Close, but the parser doesn't like the names when an alias is set.

Comment: This worked:UPDATE CE
SET CE.sJobNumber = AD.JobNumber
FROM CostEntry CE 
    INNER JOIN ActiveCostDetails As AD 
        ON CE.lUniqueID = AD.UniqueID
WHERE CE.SEmployeeCode = '002'
    AND SubString(CostCentre, 1, 1) = sDepartmentCode
    AND substring(CostCentre, 3, 1) = sCategoryCode
    AND substring(CostCentre, 5, 2) = sOperationCode

Comment: @MAW74656: I know my eyes are getting worse as I age, but isn't that what I gave you?

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - Hmmm, your right.  Maybe I'm the one with the bad eyes!

Comment: In MAW74656's comment, sjobnumber has the table alias

Comment: @MAW74656: No problem either way. Since this worked, would you please mark this as the accepted answer?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: See, I told you my eyes were getting bad! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Once you have set an alias name for the table, you cannot use the table name. Try your query this way, it will work.

```
UPDATE CostEntry CE 

        INNER JOIN 
            ActiveCostDetails AD 
            ON (CE.lUniqueID = AD.UniqueID)

           SET CE.sJobNumber = AD.JobNumber

         WHERE CE.SEmployeeCode = '002'
           AND SubString(CostCentre, 1, 1) = sDepartmentCode
           AND substring(CostCentre, 3, 1) = sCategoryCode
           AND substring(CostCentre, 5, 2) = sOperationCode
```

Comment: This is true in case of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
UPDATE CE
SET CostEntry.sJobNumber = ActiveCostDetails.JobNumber
FROM CostEntry CE 
INNER JOIN ActiveCostDetails As AD ON CostEntry.lUniqueID = ActiveCostDetails.UniqueID       
     WHERE CostEntry.SEmployeeCode = '002'
       AND SubString(CostCentre, 1, 1) = sDepartmentCode
       AND substring(CostCentre, 3, 1) = sCategoryCode
       AND substring(CostCentre, 5, 2) = sOperationCode
```