# Update Particular Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have four tables (simplified version)

Clients:

```
    ClientID
    ManagerID
    UserID
    VolunteerID
```

Managers

```
    ManagerID
    TeamID
```

Users

```
  UserID
```

Teams

```
  TeamID
```

I need to to update the user ID  (Client.UserID) on a particular Client  for a particular Team

I have come up with the following but it doesnt seem to be working - the user ID on the client is not being altered:

```
    UPDATE C
    SET C.UserID = 28 
    FROM vTeams T 
    INNER JOIN Vmanagers M ON T.TeamID = M.TeamID
    INNER JOIN dbo.vClients C ON M.ManagerID = C.ManagerID
    INNER JOIN vUsers U ON C.UserID = U.UserID
    WHERE 
    T.TeamID = 251
```

TIA

Comment: Have you tried Selecting data from these joins and where clause? does it actually return any data? because the update statement looks fine to me.

Comment: Ok sorry for this.  I did have a select statement but overlooked a changed TeamID on the select (291) - doh!!!

Comment: thought so cuz your update statement seems fine :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  this answer applies to MySQL but I don't think it works for SQL Server...sorry..I'll leave it though in case it's helpful to anyone

I haven't tested this, but there's no FROM in an UPDATE clause, and the SET comes after the JOINs.  Try something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.vClients C
    INNER JOIN Vmanagers M ON M.ManagerID = C.ManagerID
    INNER JOIN Team T ON T.TeamID = M.TeamID
#    INNER JOIN vUsers U ON C.UserID = U.UserID
# not sure if you'll need the above join, based on the example
    SET C.UserID = 28 
    WHERE 
    T.TeamID = 251
```

Comment: The Update Query specified by you will work in **PL/SQL** only it will throw up error in **SQL SERVER(T-SQL)**

Answer (score 0):

My mistake a typo on the select to check the update

Answer (score 0):

If your column is an identity table try to set it off then run your script then return it on like:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT C ON
    UPDATE C
SET C.UserID = 28 
FROM vTeams T 
INNER JOIN Vmanagers M ON T.TeamID = M.TeamID
INNER JOIN dbo.vClients C ON M.ManagerID = C.ManagerID
INNER JOIN vUsers U ON C.UserID = U.UserID
WHERE 
T.TeamID = 251

SET IDENTITY_INSERT C OFF
```

OR you can do multiple where statement separated by AND like:

```
UPDATE C
SET C.UserID = 28 
WHERE
(M.TeamID =251
AND
C.ManagerID = 251
AND
U.UserID = 251
AND
T.TeamID = 251)
```

OR this may help you:
[SQL update query syntax with inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867164/sql-update-query-syntax-with-inner-join)